# Cannot resolve PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE

Tags: android, android-intent

Anyone can solve this problem in the android studio.
I want to make an intent to file explorer to pick a file in the storage I googled for send intent to pick a file and got this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
Intent i = Intent.createChooser(intent, "File");
startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
```

And this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

I try them and both them not worked for me the same error `PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE`, `PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE` and `CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE` are not defined in android studio as variables.

the error is :

> Cannot resolve symbol 'PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE'

If anyone can solve this problem please write your solution.

Notes: Android Studio version is 3.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must define the constants yourself with some value.

```
 private static final int CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE = 8777;
 private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 8778;
```

in onActivityResult you use this code to find out where the result came from

Comment: thanks, it's work for me but I have got a question: are those values recommended or I can control it?

Comment: yes they are neccessary to find out where the onActivityResult came from